# How to retrieve the Predecessor or PredecessorList Object from Smartsheet Python SDK

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm trying to retrieve the ObjectValue attribute from the Cell object so I can get to either the Predecessor object or the PredecessorList object.

I've tried adding

```
include="object_value"
```

or

```
include="ObjectValue"
```

or various other spellings to both the

```
get_row()
```

and
    get_sheet()
methods, without success.

The Cell class appears to the only object that understands the object_value

```
self._object_value = None
```

but so far all attempts to get to it via either the Row or Sheet objects have failed.
The API doc seems to imply this should be possible, but digging through the Sheets.py and models\cells.py and models\precessors.py have so far no enlightened me to what I am missing.

Or perhaps these objects are only used for updating and not for returning what is already there?

### Craig

This is what I was shooting for:

```
             {   'columnId': 277427550218116,
                 'displayValue': '3, 5',
                 'objectValue': {   'objectType': 'PREDECESSOR_LIST',
                                    'predecessors': [   {   'rowId': 581172626515844,
                                                            'rowNumber': 3,
                                                            'type': 'FS'},
                                                        {   'rowId': 7505374650623876,
                                                            'rowNumber': 5,
                                                            'type': 'FS'}]},
                 'value': '3, 5'},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function call:

```
my_row = ss_client.Sheets.get_row(sheet_ID, row_ID, include='objectValue')
print(my_row)
```

Should give you what you're looking for. The cells with a `PREDECESSOR_LIST` objectType would look like this:

```
{
    "columnId": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    "displayValue": "5SF",
    "objectValue": {
        "objectType": "PREDECESSOR_LIST",
        "predecessors": [
            {
                "rowId": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                "rowNumber": 5,
                "type": "SF"
            }
        ]
    },
    "value": "5SF"
}
```

Comment: I really that was one of the syntaxes I tried. Thanks Steve.